# After making target targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 26, my android apk size increased by 500kb

Tags: android

After making target targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 26, my android apk size increased by 500kb.

Android apk size with(targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion as 25)=5.6mb

Android apk size with(targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion as 26)=6.2mb

After analyzing the apk I got to know that libs folder having ".so" only have increased size.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone suggest something what really happened and how to minimize this size change??

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Not yet still looking for a good answer

Comment: Can you show your dependencies? Could have something to do with overriding gms or supports on all children as well, forcing the larger newer library into every single reference. I would expect it to be a little bigger

Comment: MB, size increased becose new api 26 add new feature? This is a payment for a new api. Of course you can use tricks to reduce which are applicable to other api.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `android:extractNativeLibs` flag to false in the `<application>` element of your app manifest. This will prevent `PackageManager` from copying out `.so` files from the APK to the filesystem during installation and will have the added benefit of making delta updates of your app smaller.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, we can use Native code (C++) i.e. Android NDK (Native Development Kit) compiles this code into '.so' files. [Refer Concept](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts.html). So as you updated the Version, the '.so' files would also have updated. Thus the size got increased.